Create a button on modeline to trigger custom command
I would like to create a button in the modeline clicking on which should run the view-lossage command which shows the list of previous 300 events.
For example, I'm using the keycast package in my configuration which displays the last used command in the modeline.
I'm wondering if there is a way to click on the displayed command in the modeline from keycast and have it open the command-log buffer.
Better yet, if I can have the button open up the view-lossage buffer since it always keeps track of commands unlike the keycast-log-mode
NOTE - I'm not specifically looking for a solution to the keycast package, I'm looking for a general solution for adding or customizing the modeline to do custom behavior.

Doesn't use the mode-line, so doesn't answer your question directly, but you might be interested in library show-key.el. You can show each key in a tooltip (with or without its description), and you can log all keys as you use them (along with their descriptions).

I could not understand how tooltips work. Based on what I read it looks like tooltips will be visible when I place a mouse over something in the frame. So, this means the tooltip won't be visible unless I mouse over it. I also see the showkey-log-mode, but I understand that also needs mouse to be placed over something. Is my understanding appropriate?

No. Nothing to do with the mouse (except that mouse-button actions can also, optionally, be reported as keys). The tooltip shows you a description of each key sequence as you use it. The log shows you all key sequences you've used, in order (but you can clear the log anytime). Just load file showkey.el and try it, to see.

I tried it out. I don't like the behavior - It displays the tooltip close to my mouse/point position. And if my mouse is not close to the point, it brings the moves it there. I like the keycast mode better
